# How can I filter a table with duplicate entries to display the rows that exist the most?

Tags: mysql, sql

I hope the question makes sense.. basically I have a table called genre_tags that contains a music_id and a genre_id column

It can contain duplicate entries like so

```
music_id | genre_id
281           3
281           3
281           4
243           7
90            6
90            6
90            10
```

What I want to retrieve is the most duplicate entries based on the genre_id

So based on the example above I would be left with this result

```
music_id | genre_id
281        3
243        7
90         6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT  music_ID, genre_ID
FROM    TableName a
GROUP   BY music_ID, genre_ID
HAVING  COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) total 
                    FROM    tableName b
                    WHERE a.music_ID = b.music_ID
                    GROUP   BY music_ID, genre_ID
                    ORDER BY total DESC
                    LIMIT 1)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e942/3)

Comment: Thanks not quite, I encountered a problem and added it to the SQL fiddle, check music_id 193 - it should be returning with the genre_id of 9 but instead returns 2..

Comment: where's your link fiddle link?

Comment: almost! only trouble is i'm getting a duplicate result if the amount of duplicate entries are equal.. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75085/1
if equal the selection can just be random as long as there's only one row retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1
genre_id, count(*)
group by genre_id
order by count(*) desc
```